# How to find local maxima for all the rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, object, scipy

```
print(df.head())
```

[image]

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

ilocs_max = []

for i in range (df.shape[0]):

ilocs_max.append(argrelextrema(df.iloc[i,:].values, np.greater_equal, order=15))

df.iloc[0,:].plot(figsize=(20,8))
df.iloc[3000,:].plot(figsize=(20,8))
df.iloc[3000, [df.loc[3000].tolist()]].plot(style='.', lw=10, color='red', marker="v")
```

Answer (score 0):

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

ilocs_max = []

```
for i in range (df.shape[0]):

ilocs_max.append(argrelextrema(df.iloc[i,:].values, np.greater_equal, order=15))

#Creat a new dataframe of ilocs_max
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ilocs_max)

df.iloc[0,:].plot(figsize=(20,8))
df.iloc[3000,:].plot(figsize=(20,8))
df.iloc[3000, df1.iloc[3000].tolist()].plot(style='.', lw=10, color='red', marker="v"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

max_list = [] 

for i in range(len(df)):
    max_list.append(df.loc[i].max())
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.